# PHP code won't pull database information

Tags: php, html, sql, database

My current program, for some reason, won't register my database values even though my previous code(**looks identical but from different database tables**) works just fine.

So far I have no errors when it runs. The only thing that prints for each page is the table's title. **Also the clients page works just fine.** So the product(tv, cell, computer) and transaction page are my current issue.

My current index.php file (main program) is as follows:

```
<?php
//url /index.php?action=clients

    include('header.php'); // create top box
    include('sidemenu.php'); // create side menu
    //database connection
    include('pdo_connect.php');

    //Read data type
    $type = "";
    if (isset($_REQUEST['action']))
     $type = $_REQUEST['action'];

    //echo 'Action: {$type}';

    switch($type) {
            case 'products' : //display a list of clients
                    //define sql
                    $sql = "SELECT product_type, product_title, product_description, unit_price FROM products
                            WHERE product_type = :product_type";
                    $values = array(':product_type'=>$_GET['product_type']);
                    $products = getAll($sql);
                    //display result
                    displayProductList($products);
                    break;
            case 'clients' : //displaya list of movies
                    $sql = "SELECT first_name, last_name, email FROM p_clients";
                    $clients = getAll($sql);
                    displayClientList($clients);
                    break;
            case 'transactions' :
                    $sql = "SELECT products.product_title, products.product_description, products.unit_price, p_clients.first_name,
                            p_clients.last_name, sales.quantity FROM p_clients INNER JOIN sales, products ON p_clients.client_id = sales.client_id
                                                                                                            AND products.product_id = sales.product_id";
                    $transactions = getAll($sql);
                    displayTransactionList($transactions);
                    break;
            default:
                    defaultView();
                    break;
    }
    include('footer.php');

function defaultView() {
?>
<!-- add page content -->
<div id='content'>
    <h2>Welcome to our movie store</h2>
</div>
    <div id = 'image'></div>
    <div id = 'box'>
    <p id = 'text-box'>
    We appreciate your interest in our products and services. Please reference
    the the links provided to see our current specials for each of our clients.
    </p>
    </div>
<?php
}

    function displayProductList($products) {

    echo "<div id='content'>
            <h2>List of Products</h2>";
    echo "<table id = clients>";
    echo "<tr><td id = 'title'>Product Name</td><td id= 'title'>Description</td><td id = 'title'>Cost</td></tr>";
    //display each record
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($products); $i++){

    echo "<tr><td>{$products[$i]['product_title']} </td><td> {$products[$i]['product_description']} </td><td>
                    {$products[$i]['unit_price']} </td></tr>" ;

    }
    echo "</table>";
    echo "</div>";


    }

    function displayClientList($clients) {

    echo "<div id='content'>
            <h2>List of Clients</h2>";
    echo "<table id = 'long'>";
//        echo "<table>";
 echo "<tr><td id = 'title'>First Name</td><td id= 'title'>Last Name</td><td id = 'title'>Email</td></tr>";
    //display each record
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($clients); $i++){

    echo "<tr><td>{$clients[$i]['first_name']}</td><td> {$clients[$i]['last_name']}
    </td><td> {$clients[$i]['email']} </td></tr>";


    }

    echo "</table>";
    echo "</div>";


    }


    function displayTransactionList($transactions) {

    echo "<div id='content'>
            <h2>List of Client Transactions</h2>";
    echo "<table id = 'long'>";
//        echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr><td id = 'title'>First Name</td><td id= 'title'>Last Name</td><td id = 'title'>Product Title</td>
    <td id = 'title'>Product Description</td><td id = 'title'>Cost</td><td id = 'title'>Quantity</td></tr>";
    //display each record
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($transactions); $i++){

    echo "<tr><td>{$transactions[$i]['first_name']}</td><td> {$transactions[$i]['last_name']}
    </td><td> {$transactions[$i]['product_title']} </td><td> {$transactions[$i]['product_description']} </td><td>
    {$transactions[$i]['unit_price']} </td><td> {$transactions[$i]['quantity']} </td></tr>";


    }

    echo "</table>";
    echo "</div>";


    }


    function getAll($sql, $values =null){

    global $db;
    $statm = $db->prepare($sql);

    //Method 4
    //assign a value to named parameters using an array
    //$values= array(':genre'=>'drama');
    $statm->execute($values);

    //Fetch all records
    $result = $statm->fetchAll();
    return $result;
    }
```

The sidemenu.php file calls each one from links:

```
<div id = 'sidebar'>
<h4>Links</h4>
<ul id = "nav" class= "text-left">
<li><a href='index.php'>Home</a></li>
<li><a href='index.php?action=products&product_type=tv'>TV Products</a></li>
<li><a href='index.php?action=products&product_type=cell'>Cell Phone Products</a></li>
<li><a href='index.php?action=products&product_type=computer'>Computer Products</a></li>
<li><a href='index.php?action=clients'>List of Customers</a></li>
<li><a href='index.php?action=transactions'>List of Transactions</a></li>
<!--<li><a href='index.php?action=moviesFS&genre=sci-fi&date_out=2009-12-15'>List of Favorite Sci-Fi Movies</a></li>-->
</ul>
</div>
```

As you can see, if I type my sql into my database it works just fine:

[image]

Comment: i could be wrong but, mysqli uses "?" for prepared statements, where PDO uses ":named"

Comment: @Suing PDO can use both named - `:named` and unnamed - `?` placeholders http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php. Also, the OP is using PDO based on the methods `->execute($values)` and `->fetchAll()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
$products = getAll($sql);
```

to

```
$products = getAll($sql,$values);
```

inside `case 'products' :`

Comment: if I do that the title now doesn't display .. Not sure why

Comment: I also made sure my database had no "unneeded spacing" for each cell to avoid issues

Comment: but yes. Products should have had $values anyways. My mistake but doesn't fix the issue yet. @Sean

Comment: Oh nevermind. My tables dropped to bottom of page and missed it. That fixed it. Wow thanks. I will accept answer when it lets me

Comment: My transaction sql is giving me errors so i will try and figure out how to make the sql for what I want. Need to look up how to use 2 "Join" methods lol

Comment: Your transaction query probably needs to be `SELECT ... FROM p_clients INNER JOIN sales ON p_clients.client_id = sales.client_id INNER JOIN products  products.product_id = sales.product_id` where you join each table sequentially, not at the same time.

Comment: Ya I tried that before too. `SELECT products.product_title, products.product_description, products.unit_price, p_clients.first_name, p_clients.last_name, sales.quantity FROM p_clients INNER JOIN sales ON p_clients.client_id = sales.client_id INNER JOIN products products.product_id = sales.product_id` but get error: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.product_id = sales.product_id
LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1 `

Comment: my example was missing the `ON` after `INNER JOIN products`. should have been `INNER JOIN products ON products.product_id = sales.product_id`

Comment: I always thought u needed one ON. my bad. Thanks for clarification