# Select option doesn't connect to database

Tags: php, jquery, database, select, filter

Following my previous question: [PHP code won't pull database information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29709218/php-code-wont-pull-database-information/29709348?noredirect=1#comment47555265_29709348)

I wanted to take the transaction page to be navigated by a selection option.
In each selection option, it will use the client_id from database and filter the listing (dynamically should change page to have filtered information of transactions based on client id).

My sql (without the :client variable inside) shows the following information:

[image]

Part of my php code to use the selection option is as so:

```
<?php
//url /index.php?action=clients

include('header.php'); // create top box
include('sidemenu.php'); // create side menu
//database connection


    echo "<div id='content'>";


include('pdo_connect.php');

//Read data type
$type = "";
if (isset($_REQUEST['action']))
 $type = $_REQUEST['action'];

//echo 'Action: {$type}';

switch($type) {
    case 'transactions' :
        $sql = "SELECT products.product_title, products.product_description, products.unit_price, 
            p_clients.first_name, p_clients.last_name, sales.quantity FROM p_clients INNER JOIN 
            sales ON p_clients.client_id = sales.client_id INNER JOIN products ON products.product_id = sales.product_id
            WHERE client_id = :client_id";
        $values = array(':client_id'=>$_REQUEST['client_id']);
        $transactions = getAll($sql, $values);
                    displayTransactionList($transactions);
        break;
    default:    
        defaultView();
        break;
}
include('footer.php');

function defaultView() {
?>
<!-- add page content -->
<!--  <div id='content'>-->
    <h2>Welcome to our movie store</h2>
</div>
<div id = 'image'></div>
<div id = 'box'>
<p id = 'text-box'>
Welcome to International Electronics, the store where technology is endless. Please
feel free to browse our online store items and current customer interactions.
</p>
</div>
<?php
}

    function displayTransactionList($transactions) {

    //echo "<div id='content'>
    echo"<h2>List of Client Transactions</h2>";
echo " <p>
    <h3> Select Specific Client </h3>
    <form id='myform' method='post' action='index.php'>
            <select id = 'category' name='client_id' >
                    <option selected= 'selected'> --select id--</option>
                    <option value = '1'>Client ID 1</option>
                    <option value = '2'>Client ID 2</option>
                    <option value = '3'>Client ID 3</option>
                    <option value = '4'>Client ID 4</option>
                    <option value = '5'>Client ID 5</option>
                    <option value = '6'>Client ID 6</option>
                    <option value = '7'>Client ID 7</option>
                    <option value = '8'>Client ID 8</option>
                    <option value = '9'>Client ID 9</option>
                    <option value = '10'>Client ID 10</option>
            </select>
            </li>
    <input type='hidden' name= 'action' value = 'transactions'/>
    </form></p>";

    echo "<table id = 'long'>";
    echo "<tr><td id = 'title'>First Name</td><td id= 'title'>Last Name</td><td id = 'title'>Product Title</td>
<td id = 'title'>Product Description</td><td id = 'title'>Cost</td><td id = 'title'>Quantity</td></tr>";
    //display each record
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($transactions); $i++){

    echo "<tr><td>{$transactions[$i]['first_name']}</td><td> {$transactions[$i]['last_name']}
    </td><td> {$transactions[$i]['product_title']} </td><td> {$transactions[$i]['product_description']} </td><td> 
{$transactions[$i]['unit_price']} </td><td> {$transactions[$i]['quantity']} </td></tr>";


    }

    echo "</table>";
    echo "</div>";


    }

function getAll($sql, $values =null){

global $db;
    $statm = $db->prepare($sql);

    //Method 4
    //assign a value to named parameters using an array
    //$values= array(':genre'=>'drama');
    $statm->execute($values);

    //Fetch all records
    $result = $statm->fetchAll();
    return $result;
    }
```

Script.js to change page when select option is clicked:

document.ready(function() {

```
    $('#category').on('change', function() {
            //send form data
      $('#myform').submit();

      $('#content').html(); //also tried $('#content').html(response);
    });
});
```

sidemenu.php

```
<div id = 'top'>

<div class = "nav">
<ul id = "nav1" class= "text-left">
<div id = 'text-left'>
<ul id = "nav" class= "text-left">
<li><a href='index.php'>Home</a></li>
<li><a href='index.php?action=products&product_type=tv'>TV Products</a></li>
<li><a href='index.php?action=products&product_type=cell'>Cell Phone Products</a></li>
<li><a href='index.php?action=products&product_type=computer'>Computer Products</a></li>
<li><a href='index.php?action=clients'>List of Customers</a></li>
<li><a href='index.php?action=transactions'>List of Transactions</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

UPDATE:

if i try:
     $values = array(':client_id'=>$_POST['client_id']);

nothing changes.

[image]

![enter image description here][3]

Comment: It seems your code is correct. just check your value with $_POST not with $_REQUEST and check by doing $values = array('client_id'=>$_REQUEST['client_id']); once. Please check you are getting through $POST.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh i made an update so you can see that $_POST doesn't affect it

Comment: is it because I have a lot of other pages in my index.php file (main file) that is affecting it? the initial link at beginning of my question shows my full page

Comment: Your query is most likely failing due to an `MySQL Error - ambiguous column name 'client_id'`. Try changing to `... WHERE p_clients.client_id = :client_id`

Comment: @Sean I correct what you suggested but nothing changed when i re-ran the web page

Comment: So you ran your query without the `client_id` directly in MySQL and it works. Have you tried your query with a `client_id` directly in MySQL to see if it works first? Can you narrow down if this is a MySQL query issue, or a PHP issue?

Comment: @Sean since the database runs without the "client_id" i would think that the php that uses "client_id" is the issue (i posted a image to show the database issue)

Comment: no, don't use `:client_id` directly in MySQL. Retry the query in MySQL, but use an actual `client_id` number that is in your select - ie. `... WHERE p_clients.client_id = 5"`. You need to verify that the query works in MySQL first, using an actual value, before we can determine it is a php issue.

Comment: @Sean my bad. Yes if I run it like you said I it works.

Comment: @Sean my past project that I am referencing used the same format (however my index.php main file all used the script. This current web page I am making includes the transaction and various other pages not using the select option so i am not sure if that would affect it)

Comment: shouldn't affect it. So is your issue on initial page load of `index.php?action=transactions` as you don't have a `$_REQUEST['client_id']` defined, or is your issue when you change a value in your select that it is not reposting the form/page, or is it after your page reloads due to form post it is not picking up the `$_REQUEST['client_id']`? You need to narrow down when your issue is occuring.

Comment: @Sean the initial page load of `index.php?action=transactions` . When it loads all you see is in the image above where only the title of each column shows up.

Comment: Then you either need to set a default `client_id` value on initial page load, OR you need to do a conditional statement to append your `WHERE p_clients.client_id = :client_id` only if a `$_REQUEST['client']` is set. Right now on initial page load your query is failing (MySQL issue), as your query becomes `... WHERE p_clients.client_id =`. You need to prepare for this (fix it) on the php side.